# Negative algorithm run time

Tags: python, timeit

I'm trying to estimate time of running AES in Python. I have a code from here:

https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/1291836

And i'm using this:

https://repl.it/languages/python3

Sometimes I get negative algorithm run times. Why is it? How to measure it right?

Relevant timing loop:

```
start = timeit.timeit()
r = Rijndael("abcdefg1234567890123456789012345", block_size = 32)
ciphertext = r.encrypt("99999999999999999999999999999995")
plaintext = r.decrypt(ciphertext)
end = timeit.timeit()
```

The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/hiLJSizp).

Comment: I'm not sure why you get negative times, but a single 32-byte AES is going to be extremely fast so timing will be not so reliable; it is better to loop hundreds or thousands of times to get a more representative average.

Comment: ``timeit.timeit()`` does not give you the current time. [It gives you the execution speed of the ``pass`` statement.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit). Did you mean ``time.time`` instead?

Answer (score 2):

## Use `time.time()`, not `timeit.timeit()`.

```py
import time

# unrelated code

start = time.time()
r = Rijndael("abcdefg1234567890123456789012345", block_size = 32)
ciphertext = r.encrypt("99999999999999999999999999999995")
plaintext = r.decrypt(ciphertext)
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start  # will not be negative!
```

## Notes

#### How does `time.time()` work?

`time.time()` will always return the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC).

#### How is `timeit.timeit()` used?

Time one-liners, get average time over 1,000,000 calls.

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('4 + 5')  # runs 4 + 5 1,000,000 times; returns average speed (ms)
0.009406077000000401
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now it works. But how to call "ciphertext = r.encrypt("99999999999999999999999999999995")" 100000 times? timeit.timeit('ciphertext = r.encrypt("99999999999999999999999999999995")') does not work.

Comment: If you would like to use `timeit.timeit()` and not `time.time()` you'll have to fit everything into one line, like this `timeit.timeit(Rijndael('"abcdefg1234567890123456789012345", block_size = 32).encrypt("99999999999999999999999999999995").decrypt(ciphertext)', 'from <package> import Rijndael')`.

Comment: The second string passed to `timeit.timeit()` is the setup, which in your case involves importing `Rijndael`.